# How to plot a line graph with extreme value changes and a large data set?

Tags: python, visualization

I am trying to visualize the data that I have recorded with a benchmark. The problem that i have is that the value changes are rather big and a single data set consists of 10.000 values. I tried to visualize it with python but the resulting line graph doesn't look good. Do you have some advice or ideas how i could visualize the data better?

[image: Line Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a another style of plot that might be interesting in this case: a [boxplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot).

Answer (score 3):

###### For `x`-axis:

No one can see 10K points on a single plot, therefore

- give the user the opportunity to display desired range

How is it possible? For example,

- user DataRangeSlider from [bokeh widgets](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html)

###### For `y`-axis:

- if your largest and smallest values are intrinsic to your system and you want to display them as they are, use logarithmic scale
- if your largest and and small values are outliers, use robust  moving values, for example medians
- if your largest and and small values are outliers and you want to avoid averaging, just restrict the `y`-axis to the values of interest

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion I think it'll depend on why you want to visualize it / what you're trying to analyze. If it's appropriate, you might try something like a moving average to smooth out the sharp value changes.

[image: Covid-19 Florida Daily deaths moving average]

I got this visualization from [this blog post](https://statisticsbyjim.com/time-series/moving-averages-smoothing/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try out the moving average.